# Uninstalling a particular feature using msiexec

Tags: wix, uninstallation, windows-installer

I installed an test application which has two features (FirstFeature & SecondFeature). I want to remove only one feature (SecondFeature) from the application. I tried using REMOVE property in command line. Here is the command used to remove SecondFeature.

```
msiexec /x RemoveFeatures.msi REMOVE="SecondFeature" /L*V log.LOG
```

But it is uninstalling the complete application. Log file shows that REMOVE=ALL is added by default. Here is the log file details.

> MSI (s) (24:B4) [17:39:05:231]: Command Line: REMOVE=SecondFeature REMOVE=ALL
>
> MSI (s) (24:B4) [17:39:05:231]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'SecondFeature'.
>
> MSI (s) (24:B4) [17:39:05:231]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying REMOVE property. Its current value is 'SecondFeature'. Its new value: 'ALL'.

It indicates REMOVE property value is overridden during uninstall process. Do I need to set any other property to remove a specific feature ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you noted, /x is for uninstall. A *complete* (ALL) uninstall.

Although it may be counter intuitive you want to do an install that removes a feature.

```
msiexec /i RemoveFeatures.msi REMOVE="SecondFeature" /L*V log.LOG
```

You may also wish to add /qb or /qn to make it non-interactive / silent.

Comment: Is `RemovesFeatures.msi` a very representative name for a package? It confuses me. Which MSI package is used here? The one containing the feature, or some other?

Comment: I just used the MSI name that the original poster used.  Put  SomeProduct.msi there instead if it helps you.