# MSI Properties Empty on Passive, Basic UI, and No UI Install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am working on an installer with a handful of custom actions that look for values in the following MSI properties:

- ADDLOCAL
- ADDDEFAULT
- REINSTALL
- REMOVE

When running the installer with the full UI, these properties contain lists of comma-separated feature names as appropriate given the options that are selected by the user. However, when I run the installer in passive mode or with only a basic UI (or no UI) from the command line, I find that the properties are empty/blank. It is only when I explicitly set them from the command line that they have any value. This is an acceptable work-around, but it would be much better if these could take on some kind of default, such as "all", without requiring values to be passed on the command line. Is there some way I can specify this in WiX (which I am using to build the MSI) or do I have to do something in the custom action code (or something else entirely)?

I have looked at the property reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I did not see any mention of how one could specify *default* features for these properties.

What I also found interesting is if I do specify a feature this way on the command line during install, it seems to be stored for the uninstall in the REMOVE property (in other words, I do not have to pass any parameters when uninstalling in any mode). Is this a feature that I can rely on? Will it automatically update if someone modifies the installation later?

I'm running WiX 3.5.2519 and using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual C++ for the custom action code. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Edit:

Actually, I was wrong. It appears that the REMOVE property is *always* set to "all" when uninstalling and running in one of these modes, even if I pass a different value on the command line or only install a subset of features. This seems broken. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
C:\> msiexec REMOVE=FeatureName /passive /l* uninstall.log /x Product.msi
```

It will completely ignore what I specify for "FeatureName" and use "all" in its place.

Comment: I turned on verbose logging (the /l*v switch) for uninstallation and found this: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'FeatureName'. Then I saw this a couple of lines later: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying REMOVE property. Its current value is 'FeatureName'. Its new value: 'ALL'. Why did this happen?

Comment: I just found this too: "Command Line: REMOVE=FeatureName REBOOTPROMPT=S REMOVE=ALL CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\ CLIENTUILEVEL=2 CLIENTPROCESSID=4132". I did not pass the REMOVE property twice; is some default thing adding this without my knowledge?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254500/uninstalling-a-particular-feature-using-msiexec

Comment: As it turns out, I really don't want to give these particular properties defaults besides the empty string because they can conflict with one another if they're all defined (for example, it would install then immediately uninstall)! It seems like this is a long way around to discovering the proper way to specify remove targets during a silent uninstall and that there is no easy way to say "install everything by default" and have my custom action know about it, though I haven't explored transforms fully yet.

Comment: During a silent *uninstall*, everything is uninstalled. That's what uninstall is for. So msi correctly sets `REMOVE=ALL`. If you need to uninstall only some features (and possibly install some other features), you would run in install mode `/i` and set `REMOVE` property to the list of features you want to remove (and `ADDLOCAL` to the list to add/install).

Comment: Right, and that's what I found from the linked question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a recommended practice that all properties to be used by the installation be entered into the [Property table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/1f4215b2-dc71-4e6e-bc2e-3b43316806b9) with an initial value. The installer sets the properties to these values at the launch of the installation. Properties for which a blank is an acceptable value and properties built into the installer do not need to be initialized.

You can then change the default value programmatically or on the command line as described here: [Using Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/5a2f1cd4-2bbd-414a-a814-8b9fdab434b4).

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid changing properties on the command line as it would be error-prone, so I think the programmatic approach is what I'm looking for. Can you provide an example for me, please? I have looked through the MSDN pages you reference without much luck. I'm still quite new to installers and WiX.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment, I do see the examples for MsiGetProperty and MsiSetProperty in the links provided, but I'm unclear about how one would set defaults for properties in the property table ahead of calling the custom actions (since I create the installer with WiX).

Comment: OK, it was staring me in the face the whole time: <Property Id="ADDLOCAL" Secure="yes">ALL</Property> <Property Id="REMOVE" Secure="yes">ALL</Property> Thanks again!

Comment: I should also mention that specifying both ADDLOCAL=ALL and REMOVE=ALL at the same time is probably not what you want.

Comment: I am not a WiX user, so I can't say how to do this with that tool, but that might be the best method for you if you are already using it to create your installer.  Another option is to create a customization transform, there is an example on MSDN : [A Customization Transform Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/028b1d01-3b66-4640-98f9-ca33f90ca516) . That is a common approach to enabling a base package install different features for different users.

Comment: I already figured it out (see my comment about the WiX Property element). Still, thanks again for the extra information. I did not know about transforms.

Comment: I'm still giving you credit here because even though it turns out that I don't want to actually give these values defaults, this is the right way to do it if I did.

Answer (score 4):

Your custom actions probably shouldn't examine those properties. Instead they should examine the feature and/or component states of the product, depending on what they're trying to do. In [conditional statement syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012.aspx), this looks like `$component-action` or `&feature-action` (where you use the name of the component or feature whose action you are trying to condition against). In C++ (for inside the custom action) this looks like [`MsiGetFeatureState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370117.aspx) or [`MsiGetComponentState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370113.aspx), and these are of course made available through similar means in most other languages (such as `session.FeatureRequestState` / `session.ComponentRequestState` in a language you shouldn't use).

Comment: I say *probably* because if your actions are scheduled early enough, the component and feature states haven't been determined, and the properties are your only option.

Comment: This does seem like a better way for checking these things (in fact I am using !feature-state and &feature-action conditionals for a couple new actions I personally added recently). Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a lot of legacy code/XML in this particular case which I can't really update right now. I will keep this in mind though for when I get some free time to review it more, so thank you very much for the pointers (+1). BTW, which language are you referring to that I shouldn't use? It looks like Java or C#. Why would that be a bad idea?

Comment: Also, in reference to your comment, I am actually scheduling a few actions quite early, so, yes, I probably won't be able to change that behavior as you've noted. It's very good to know this as I've discovered, so thanks again (+1).

Comment: Glad this all helps!

I was referring to VB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371662.aspx Technically automation doesn't have to be VB, but the use of VB in a .msi should be discouraged.

Comment: Ah, OK. I have very little experience with VB, but I should have recognized that. Thanks!