# Uninstalling Windows SDK in a msi installer project

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I have created a msi installer using microsoft visual studio 2022, where i am able to install signtool.exe reading from [signtool installation steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869552/how-to-install-signtool-exe-for-windows-10)

This was the command which i had used in a .bat file: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MicrosoftTrustedSigningClientTools\winsdksetup.exe /features OptionId.SigningTools /q /norestart

[image: Signtool installation details]

**Is there any similar uninstall command as well, which i can use in the uninstall custom action of my msi to remove the signtool.exe and its dependencies ?**

Answer (score 1):

You question is actually no related with VS, for you requirement, I think you have two ways:

1, Get the location of the exe file and use command like this in BAT file to remove it:

```
@echo off
REM Replace the path below with the actual path to your signtool.exe
DEL "C:\Path\To\signtool.exe"
echo signtool.exe has been deleted.
pause
```

2, Using msiexec:

Take a look of this answer:

[How to uninstalling a particular feature using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255767/6261890)

And this is the official document of it:

[msiexec document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec)

/qn should helps you quiet uninstall.

Comment: awesome this helps me especially that second one. Thanks a million.

Comment: the msiexec is not working as i have installed using winsdk.exe file. Is there any way to give commands to the .exe file, windowssdk.exe file to uninstall it. I tried also using msiexec for msi file for signtool which i have that also didn't work.